# SQL Query to Identify All Contacts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, sql

I am looking for a way to identify all contact within Marketing Cloud who don't have an email or sms activity within the past 2 years. I've already done a data extract to get that activity but I want to cross match it to something. I've tried _ListSubscribers and _Subscribers but that doesn't get me everyone I've ever contacted on each of my BU's. Is there a method like a _Contacts table or something I can use to pull them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to JOIN the [_Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) view with the [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) view and the [_SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) view.

- _Sent will show you the subscribers who received emails, however, this is limited to the subscribers emailed in the last 6 months (not 2 years like you asked).
- _SMSMessageTracking will give you subscribers who received SMS messages. In the documentation, I don't see any limitations on how far back you can go.

The SQL query you need would look something like this:

```
SELECT SubscriberID, EmailAddress
FROM _Subscribers
LEFT JOIN _Sent ON _Subscribers.SubscriberID = _Sent.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _SMSMessageTracking ON _Subscribers.SubscriberID = _SMSMessageTracking.SubscriberID
WHERE _Subscribers.SubscriberID = NULL OR _SMSMessageTracking.SubscriberID = NULL
```

You can write this SQL query in a Query Activity or a more user-friendly tool like [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-15) which does not require you to have SQL knowledge.

The reasons your subscribers view may be different from what you expect could be related to the following:

- The contacts you're expecting might not be defined as a Subscriber. If they were uploaded in data extensions, a Subscriber relationship needs to be defined for that data extension.
- If you have the feature enabled described in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199545/can-a-data-retention-policy-be-applied-to-the-all-subscribers-list), your contacts could have been deleted from your Subscribers view because of the Data Retention Policy of the data extension.
- I'm not sure if the Contacts definition in Mobile Studio is the same as Subscribers in Email Studio.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank so much for the suggestion, I think this helps answer the question in some aspect but unfortunately I still need the entire history of my BU's, and that's really what i'm looking to get. A full historical extract of my active contacts so that i can match it to a list of people that i have mailed to in the past 2 years. The remaining is what will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filtered Mobile List to create a list which you can query which. I would suggest following this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1) You will need to modify the filter in step 2 to get the results you desire.